# Wordpress User creation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

I am almost a total newbie to Wordpress.

I want to create a website where users can register themselves using either their Email ID or their Google, Facebook and similar accounts.

As I understand WP upon installation provides certain pre-defined users as explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).  Again as I understand these roles are meant for users who will specifically log in from the backend of the WP CMS to carry out stuff as per their roles.

But then again these are the pre defined users of WP. I want a surfer to be able to register on the website and add posts on their own.

Questions

1. Is this at all possible in WP?
2. If so how? Coding or using extending the basic functionality of WP extensions or plugins?
3. Can the user (not any of the reserved users) then create and publish a post on their own?
4. Can you refer some resources where the basic WP capabilities can be explored?

I hope my questions are clear

Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this blog article on this very topic.
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/29/login-wordpress-using-social-network/

Basically you are wanting Social logins. You can search wordpress.org for plugins to make this easier for you to implement. Basically you would download the desired plugin , install it and test it. (plugins have instillation instructions inside them usually in a text file.

Comment: Thanks Lee. This helps tremendously.  I could not find an answer to whether a user can register using an email Id, but this is a very good beginning. I have added another question to my original post

Comment: 3. Will depend on the functionality of the plugin.
4. There are lots of Video tutorials on Wordpress, to get you started on all it can do. Google wordpress video tutorial or training.